# Get the profile picture set by the user on xPortal app via API

Tags: multiversx

Is there a way to GET the profile picture the user has set on xPortal app via the API?

The following:

```
https://id.maiar.com/users/photos/profile/{ADDRESS}
```

worked in the past, but after the rebranding it returns a `404`:

```
default backend - 404
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the new valid endpoint:

```
https://id-api.multiversx.com/users/photos/profile/{ADDRESS}
```

---

E.g.:

```
https://id-api.multiversx.com/users/photos/profile/erd1p63rhxp8rsjusw885haal9myazpwqv94u5md6x308ke4zp9rp0jqquffl7
```

redirects (302) to

```
https://api.multiversx.com/nfts/ANDMCCTEAM-be19dc-01/thumbnail
```

and this one redirects (302) to

```
https://media.elrond.com/nfts/thumbnail/ANDMCCTEAM-be19dc-56d80ac1
```